# App closes after facebook login Android (Facebook SDK version 4.6.0)?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

While trying to login an android application using Facebook login the app says logged in successfully and then closes however on searching about the same i came across some solutions but nothing helped.adding the code snip for reference.

```
/*login screen*/
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                                    GraphResponse response) {

                            String profilePicUrl="";
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", object.optString("name"));
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", object.optString("email"));
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", object.optString("id").toString());

                            try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                            Fb_fname= object.optString("name");
                            FbId=object.optString("id").toString();

                                if (data.has("picture")) {
                                  profilePicUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                }
                            registerfacebook(Fb_fname,FbId,profilePicUrl);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture.type(large)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
```

and the code for the home screen is as follows.

```
/*home screen*/

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Log.i("Username","hii");
```

The above is a code module on the pages involved.Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: did you add the `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: yes I have applied it .

Comment: check if you have any exception...in catch block and where is `registerfacebook()`.. function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times if all goes good you can check the logout section as maybe you missed to end the login session created at the time of social login. In that case you would not be able to login efficiently so its recommended to handle the social login sessions at the time of logout.